# Can't update Ruby resulting in Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, homebrew, activesupport

I checked the list for   http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html  trying to reinstall Rails and have been trying to update it for the last 2+ hours.

This is what I get at the terminal:

```
Stevens-MBP:Desktop Steven$ rvm install ruby-2.3.1
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.3.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more    information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
automake 1.15
Error: You must `brew link autoconf` before automake can be installed
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Here is additional information:

```
Stevens-MBP:Desktop Steven$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version,  simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
Stevens-MBP:Desktop Steven$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
Stevens-MBP:Desktop Steven$
```

When I type `sudo gem install rails` I get:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
 activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

Comment: The error message is telling you to run `brew link autoconf` before it can upgrade automake.  Did you do that?

Comment: can you just try rvm install 2.3.1? I feel like I installed that version that way a few months ago

Comment: @infused you got that right. After I ran "brew link autoconf" everything has been installing smoothly. I was even able to install 2.3.1 finally. Thank you. Can't believe I missed that small part.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo gem install rails

Rule #1 when working with RVM (or rbenv) is do NOT use `sudo` except for multi-user installs (which are not encouraged by the maintainers).

By default, RVM and rbenv manage Rubies installed using them in a separate folder in your home directory where you already have full privileges to install/update/remove Rubies or gems. Use whichever manager you want to install/remove Ruby and set it as a default, then use `gem install ...` to install gems.

Using `sudo` changes your effective user to the sysadmin, which has a different idea where the RVM/rbenv managed Rubies and the associated gems live.

After issuing `rvm install ruby-2.3.1` you should do

```
rvm use 2.3.1 --default
```

to tell RVM which Ruby you want to use.

`rvm info` will tell you what RVM knows about its world.

The error you get is probably because your vendor-installed version of Rails is out of date, and `sudo` is the root-cause of that occurring. Try `gem install rails` and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

First upgrade ruby with `rvm upgrade 2.1.2 2.3.1`
That should do the trick if you have rvm installed correctly. Once it's done you can install rails with `sudo gem install rails`